# SMTP Connect() in phpmailer with postfix

Tags: php, phpmailer, postfix-mta, webmin

Trying to send an email with `phpmailer` return this error:

> 2019-09-09 16:48:39 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 primarydomain.mx ESMTP
>   Postfix (Ubuntu) 2019-09-09 16:48:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO
>   www.subdomain.mx 2019-09-09 16:48:39 SERVER -> CLIENT:
>   250-primarydomain.mx 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 10240000 250-VRFY
>   250-ETRN 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
>   250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8BITMIME 250-DSN 250 SMTPUTF8 2019-09-09
>   16:48:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2019-09-09 16:48:39 SERVER ->
>   CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 2019-09-09 16:48:39 Error SMTP:
>   Imposible conectar al servidor SMTP. 2019-09-09 16:48:39 CLIENT ->
>   SERVER: QUIT 2019-09-09 16:48:39 SERVER -> CLIENT:
>   f5�|�+x�]?�M캅<�������9J���!��D(��"�n�6�m��
>   ��C��G0�O�vjdK@��&�z�����VŔ��"�����
>   �!C�Qf�yE-��M�YWrp8Dʕ������\N<���L�8�LsE�WZ�M�=��1c�@�=6�h,�$��rμ#��D����t�"f���ʹ٢3��y��:Z�>&�u�?`��O�[�%��
>   ���^�p���E��Y�8,��P쓞C
>   B�Sd��:84؃$<����|E:�_��nR��iO��e��7듣6��Ρ�(��N�,����P;���]f���{SS���"��<���
>   2019-09-09 16:48:39 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
>   f5�|�+x�]?�M캅<�������9J���!��D(��"�n�6�m��
>   ��C��G0�O�vjdK@��&�z�����VŔ��"�����
>   �!C�Qf�yE-��M�YWrp8Dʕ������\N<���L�8�LsE�WZ�M�=��1c�@�=6�h,�$��rμ#��D����t�"f���ʹ٢3��y��:Z�>&�u�?`��O�[�%��
>   ���^�p���E��Y�8,��P쓞C
>   B�Sd��:84؃$<����|E:�_��nR��iO��e��7듣6��Ρ�(��N�,����P;���]f���{SS���"��<���
>   2019-09-09 16:48:39 SMTP Connect() falló.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting SMTP
>   Connect() falló.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

This is my `postix` global settings, any help?

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = primarydomain.mx
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, primarydomain.mx, localhost.mx, , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
allow_percent_hack = no
```

PD: I can use without any issues my emails with `Thunderbird` or `Outlook` clients, this is just hapenning me when a i try to use `phpmailer` to send emails.

Comment: please see that the phpmailer errors are in spanish, i don't know why, sorry

Comment: Follow the link to the guide - you have a failure immediately after STARTTLS, which is a well-known problem that usually indicates that the CA certificate bundle on your server is out of date, though it can be other things too, all discussed in the guide.